# Larger Audio Files Getting Corrupted after upload to Google Drive

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I m using below code to upload files from Android mobile to Google Drive. This code is written in Async task.

```
public Object loadInBackground() {

    GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(mycontext);
    assert account != null;
    mDriveServiceHelper = new DriveServiceHelper(getGoogleDriveService(mycontext, account, "E Aid"));


    mDriveServiceHelper.searchFile(file.getName(), "*/*").addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<GoogleDriveFileHolder>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<GoogleDriveFileHolder> googleDriveFileHolders) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();

            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(gson.toJson(googleDriveFileHolders));
                // Log.i(TAG, jsonArray.toString());
                if (jsonArray.length() != 0) {
                    HyperLog.i(TAG, file.getName() + " found at GD");
                    //Duplicate File, Delete at Local Level
                  
                } else {
                    HyperLog.i(TAG, "Check " + file.getName() + " Not Found ");

                    mDriveServiceHelper.uploadFile(file, "*/*", folderId, mycontext);



                }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });


    return null;
}
```

Here is code for uploadfile method.

```
 public Task<GoogleDriveFileHolder> uploadFile(final java.io.File localFile, final String mimeType, @Nullable final String folderId, final Context context) {
        return Tasks.call(mExecutor, new Callable<GoogleDriveFileHolder>() {
            @Override
            public GoogleDriveFileHolder call() throws Exception {
                // Retrieve the metadata as a File object.
                Log.i(TAG, "Special Check Inside Upload Function");
                List<String> root;
                if (folderId == null) {
                    root = Collections.singletonList("root");
                } else {

                    root = Collections.singletonList(folderId);
                }

                File metadata = new File()
                        .setParents(root)
                        .setMimeType(mimeType)
                        .setName(localFile.getName());


                FileContent fileContent = new FileContent(mimeType, localFile);

                File fileMeta = mDriveService.files().create(metadata, fileContent).execute();
                GoogleDriveFileHolder googleDriveFileHolder = new GoogleDriveFileHolder();
                googleDriveFileHolder.setId(fileMeta.getId());
                googleDriveFileHolder.setName(fileMeta.getName());
               

               
                if (googleDriveFileHolder.getId() != null) {
                    Log.i(TAG, localFile.getAbsolutePath() + " has uploaded Successfully ");
                    
                  

                   
                }
                return googleDriveFileHolder;


            }
        });
    }
```

both codes are working fine for uploading files upto 5 to 6 Mbs. As soon as file size increased like 30 Mb, the file is being uploading but gets corrupted and can not be open after downloading from google drive.

Can someone help to fix this, what is missing which can be added here.

Comment: How is it corrupted? You could at least tell size in bytes of original and corrupted file.

Comment: File size are same before and after upload. But the audio file can not be played by any media player after upload, it gives error unable to load. File size are in range of 20 to 35 Mb